# Starting position for replace function in db2

Tags: replace, db2

I'm converting some Access VBA functionality to DB2 and found a vital difference.  VBA lets you specify the starting point in the character string you're working on.  DB2 doesn't have that option.  It starts from position 1 and replaces whatever you want to be replaced in the whole string. How can I make DB2 start the replace at a specified place in the string? For example, my string is "Incongruent Plastics Incorporated" and I want to replace the second "Inc" at position 22 with "Inc". I'm doing this in a WHILE loop, going through long strings, replacing parts of them until they are less than a specified maximum (15 or 30 depending on the field).

I looked at the Locate function, but I'm not sure that's right.

```sql
Replace(a.PAYEE_STD_NAME, B.FullWord, B.abbreviation, B.mLastWord)
```

Where `a.PAYEE_STD_NAME` is the string I'm looking at, `B.FullWord` is what I want to replace, `B.abbreviation` is what I want to replace it with, and `B.mLastWord` is the position where I want to start replacing.  Something like Replace("Incongruent Plastics Incorporated","Incorporated","Inc",22)

I expect the characters to be replaced starting in the position I need, towards the back of the string, not in the beginning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not that good at DB2, but that limitation can generally be worked around by using `SUBSTR`

The equivalent of `Replace(a.PAYEE_STD_NAME, B.FullWord, B.abbreviation, B.mLastWord)` would be:

```
CONCAT(SUBSTR(a.PAYEE_STD_NAME, 1, B.mLastWord - 1), Replace(SUBSTR(a.PAYEE_STD_NAME, b.mLastWord), B.FullWord, B.abbreviation))
```

This assumes `b.mLastWord` is greater than 1, if it's 1 you can use a normal `REPLACE`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I thought I had this working but it turns out I didn't so I searched up the problem and lo and behold!  My own question!  Anyway, I tried your solution and got an error.  iNavigator flagged b.mLastword in REPLACE(SUBSTR(a.ADDRESS, b.mLastWord), B.FullWord, B.abbreviation), saying it wasn't valid.  I think it's looking for a numeric value there, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using `REGEXP_REPLACE` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061496.html

and possibly consider recusrive SQL rather than looping logic

Comment: That looks like it would work perfectly except I'm not on version 11 of db2.  Any ideas for someone back in version 9?